# Attach database in sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

For this example I have `db_master.sqlite` and `db_1.sqlite` in the working directory.

Everything seems to be working fine when I do this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_master.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('ATTACH DATABASE "db_1.sqlite" AS db_1')
c.execute('SELECT * FROM db_1.my_table')
conn.commit()
c.fetchall()
```

I get the column data back as expected. But when I close the connection and re-open it, the database no longer appears to be attached.

```
conn.close()
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_master.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM db_1.my_table')
c.fetchall()
```

> OperationalError: no such table: db_1.my_table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You attach databases to *your connection*, not to a specific database. You'll have to re-attach each time you create a new database connection.

From the [`ATTACH DATABASE` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html):

> The `ATTACH DATABASE` statement adds another database file **to the current database connection.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks Martjin, is there any way you know of to attach a database like I am trying to do? I want a nested table structure.

Comment: @AlexG: just execute your `ATTACH` statements each time you connect.

Comment: @AlexG: however, if you are always need for those tables to exist, why are you putting them into a separate database? Just put them all in the same database if you need access to them each and every time.

Comment: Good advice, I'll do one of those two options